# Excel pivot table search filter with and / or

Tags: excel, pivot

I am trying to filter a field in a pivot table so that it only shows some values.

I have a field which is product code and I want to only show the product codes that are H01, P07, F04, L43, ... and the list continues. For the moment, I have to click the little arrow next to the field, do a search on the code and then click on the checkbox add current filter to selection and hit ok. I have to do this 20 times for the 20 different product codes.

Is there a way to enter in the search box immediately H01, P07, F04, L43, ... just once and then hit ok and I ll see all the product codes immediately?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: One solution would be to create another column in your raw data to flag the product codes you want to display in your pivot table (_e.g._, as `0` or `1`), and then add that column as a filter to the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through pivot items and select the ones that match your criteria using VBA as suggested here:

[Looping through report filters to change visibility doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387938/excel-vba-looping-through-report-filters-to-change-visibility-doesnt-work)

The only issue I've had with this sort of approach is that you cannot deselect the only selected item, so if you are going to be deselecting then you should make sure to select particular items as well.