# Error '1004': Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class

Tags: excel, hide, pivot-table, pivotitem, vba

i got the below code from here: [Looping through report filters to change visibility doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387938/looping-through-report-filters-to-change-visibility-doesnt-work) where the solution is marked as working. After modifying according to my need, it is like this:

```
With pt.PivotFields(6)
    .ClearAllFilters
     If .PivotItems.Count > 0 Then

        'goofy but necessary
        Set firstPi = .PivotItems(1)

        For Each pi In .PivotItems

            If firstPi.Visible = False Then
                firstPi.Visible = True
            End If

             'Don't loop through firstPi
            If pi.Value <> firstPi.Value Then
                itemValue = pt.GetPivotData("[Measures].[Nr of Cancelled]", "[Characteristics].[Reason]", pi.Name).Value

                rw = rw + 1
                nwSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value = pi.Name
                nwSheet.Cells(rw, 2).Value = pi.Visible
                If itemValue < 2000 Then
                    If pi.Visible = True Then
                        pi.Visible = False 'Error here
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox pi.Value
                    If pi.Visible = False Then
                        pi.Visible = True 'Error here
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

              'Finally perform the check on the first pivot item
              If firstPi > 2000 Then
                  firstPi.Visible = True
              Else
                  firstPi.Visible = False
              End If
           End If
    End With
```

I see that the whole code is working fine and I'm facing error only the lines `pi.Visible = True` or `pi.Visible = False`

I'm not sure where I've done wrong for the code not to work.

When I was searching internet for the soltuion, I came across this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/114822 where MS mentioned that **Only** **contiguous items in a PivotTable Field can be hidden.**
Does that mean that items in my table are not contiguous? Can anyone help me? I'm lost here.

Comment: ***Are*** the items in your table are contiguous?  I doubt anyone on SO can answer that.

Comment: How can I determine whether it's contiguous or not? I have no idea reg this

Comment: Can I see your Excel File? If yes, then please upload it in a free file sharing site and share the link here. Also ensure that if you have any confidential data then to replace that with dummy data.

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout thanks for your response. But all the file sharing sites are restricted. I cannot do that. However, I found a way to solve the task. Please find the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any solution for the Error. But I found another way to achieve the task. I used array to store all the Items to hide and Items to be visible so that I can call either HiddenItemsList or VisibleItemsList:

```
    For Each pvtitem In pt.PivotFields(6).PivotItems
        On Error GoTo skipreason
        itemValue = pt.GetPivotData("[Measures].[Cancelled]", "[Characteristics].[Reason]", pvtitem.Name).Value
        If itemValue < 2000 Then
            hiddenReasons(hiddenCount) = pvtitem.Name
            hiddenCount = hiddenCount + 1
        Else
            visibleReasons(visibleCount) = pvtitem.Name
            visibleCount = visibleCount + 1
        End If

Sheets("Cancels").PivotTables("Cancels").PivotFields( _
    "[Characteristics].[Reason].[Reason]" _
    ).VisibleItemsList = Array(visibleReasons())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 years and six months late, but I may have found a solution while putzing around with my script. Errors could only be replicated on my end when the pivot table had to resize, and there were elements below the pivot table. This had nothing to do with whether the resizing would cause it to overrun or not (e.g. I had a "top 10" filter applied) - in fact for me the table was attempting to shrink. Once I stacked my pivot tables side-to-side rather than vertically, I could no longer replicate the error.